# How to reconcile microservice "share nothing" principle with "independence"

Tags: design-patterns, service, architecture, microservices

Let's say my entire domain has entities like

```
[
   {
      id: 1,
      name: "Joe",
      age: 16,
      hometown: "Los Angeles",
      friends: [2]
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      name: "Jack",
      age: 83,
      hometown: "Phily",
      friends: [1, 3]
   },
   {
      id: 3,
      name: "Susy",
      age: 50,
      hometown: "Dayton",
      friends: [2]
   }
]
```

and I decide to have 2 separate services

1. Person Info Manager
2. Friend Manager

to deal with these entities. The way I would literally interpret "share nothing" would be have that each service has storage like

```
[
   {
      id: 1,
      name: "Joe",
      age: 16,
      hometown: "Los Angeles"
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      name: "Jack",
      age: 83,
      hometown: "Phily"
   },
   {
      id: 3,
      name: "Susy",
      age: 50,
      hometown: "Dayton"
   }
]
```

for 1. and

```
{
    1: [2],
    2: [1, 3],
    3: [2]
}
```

for 2. So basically the overall information has been partitioned into being stored in 2 places (except the `id`s which I guess are shared).

Here are some potential problems that I see with this:

- In the case of the Friend Manager service, since all you have is `id`s, there is probably nothing useful that can be done in overall system without combing information from this service with information from Person Info Manager service.
- To follow the previous point, let's say that we want a UI where users can manage friend ships. Then we will need to query the Friend Manager Service to get this information and perform "joins" by `id`. This means that Friend Manager Service has a dependency on Person Info Manager service, or there is some third service that has a dependency on both.

To remedy those potential problems (I'm not sure they are real problems; that's why I am asking S.O.) we could have that they share more data. Let's say that you need at minimum to know a person's `name` in order to manage friendships. Then we could have

```
{
    info: {
        1: {
          name: "Joe"
        },
        2: {
          name: "Jack"
        },
        3: {
          name: "Susy"
        }
    },
    friendships: {
        1: [2],
        2: [1, 3],
        3: [2]
    }
}
```

so that now the Friend Manager service can work independently. Some potential downsides with this are

- Extra storage cost from duplicate data
- The names in in Friend Manager service could be stale because of lag in receiving updates from the Person Info Manager service or because of error. Whereas if the Friend Manager service were to query Person Info Manager service for names whenever needed, then it would always have the up-to-date info (the query could also account for persons who have been removed).

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

- person info and friend manager both sound as way too small for being separate microservices, which should as a rule of thumb map to a [Bounded Context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html). Imagine bounded contexts are main processes happening in your domain, not groups of entities.
- extra costs of duplicate storage is most cases not a problem, we are not talking about Twitter scale, and even they solve it with data duplication https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Twitter-Timeline-Scalability
- to maintain data consistency like in your example, you need to define acceptable consistency level (according to business rules / domain logic) across different bounded contexts. One principle which comes here very often is [Eventual Consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). Search in conjuction with Domain Driven Design, you are bound to discover a lot of stuff there :)
- microservices calling other microservices directly can also work in some cases, I mean look at [Netflix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZ3wIuvmHeM) ;)